# How to use JQuery in SVG?

Tags: jquery, svg

This is the code I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="100" height="100">

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" id="cir" fill="green" onclick="showFrame()"/>

    <script xlink:href="jQuery.js" language="JavaScript"></script>

    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[

        function showFrame() {
            alert($("#cir"));
        }
    ]]></script>
</svg>
```

If the jquery can work,I can see a alert, but nothing.

Where I write wrong?

Comment: Is this a `.html` file? Do you have jQuery library included? What browser are you using? Anyway, if you like to manipulate svg objects I recommand you to use [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a standalone .svg file?

Comment: yes, this is a standalone .svg file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me once I include the jQuery library from a CDN instead.

**Are you sure `jQuery.js` exists at the correct directory?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="100" height="100">

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" id="cir" fill="green" onclick="showFrame()"/>

    <script xlink:href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[

        function showFrame() {
            alert($("#cir"));
        }
    ]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: I saw you the answer and I'm found the reason.my jquery is bad.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is not what you want to do. Mixing JS logic with SVG. You wouldn't do this with HTML and JS either (at least you should not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" id="cir" fill="green" onclick="showFrame()"/>
</svg>
```

Then just as you would do regulary somewhere in the HTML

```
<body>
...
<script>
   $("#cir").on("click", function(){alert($("#cir");});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I only write a standalone .SVG file, no html.